# Inserting records from a table to another using dynamic SQL with conditions to convert data type

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse

I have two tables whose structures as follows:

```
 table_A

 CREATE TABLE table_A
  ( 
    col_a varchar(100),
    col_b bigint,
    col_c datetime
  )

  table_b
  --Note that columns are same--
  CREATE TABLE table_B
   (
    col_a varchar(10),
    col_b varchar(10),
    col_c varchar(20)
   )
```

Now I want to `INSERT` data into `table_A` from `table_B` with proper data type conversion.

Below is the SQL string:

```
 INSERT INTO table_A(col_a,col_b,col_c)
 SELECT CONVERT(varchar,col_a),CONVERT(INT,col_b),CONVERT(datetime,col_c) FROM table_B
```

So far so good.

Now I want generate the SQL dynamically with the help of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

For this I have followed the below steps:

Step 1:
Join the Information Schema for the above two tables viz table_A and table_B and store them in a `#TempTable`. Lets assume that `#TempTable` has an `ID` column that is `IDENTITY(1,1)` but that doesn't follow any sequence like 1,2,3...(Typically this happens in Synapse SQL)

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT S.COLUMN_NAME AS Src_Col, 
         S.DATA_TYPE AS Src_dtype,
         D.COLUMN_NAME AS Dest_Col,
         D.DATA_TYPE AS Dest_dtype,
         CASE WHEN S.DATA_TYPE NOT LIKE D.DATA_TYPE THEN 
                   'CONVERT('+ '''' + D.DATA_TYPE + '''' + ',' + '''' + S.DATA_TYPE + '''' + ')'
                    ELSE S.DATA_TYPE AS Modified_Col
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA S
   JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS D
   ON S.COLUMN_NAME = D.COLUMN_NAME AND S.TABLE_NAME = REPLACE(D.TABLE_NAME,'_B','_A')
```

Step 2:
Iterate over #TempTable to fetch the `Modified_Col` values

```
 SET @Max_ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #TempTable);
 SET @Min_ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM #TempTable);

 SET @ColToInsert = '';
 SET @Dest_Col = '';
 WHILE @Min_ID <= @Max_ID
 BEGIN
   SET @ColToInsert = (SELECT @ColToInsert + Modified_Col FROM #TempTable T WHERE T.ID = @Min_ID);
   SET @Dest_Col = (SELECT @Dest_Col + Dest_Col FROM #TempTable T WHERE T.ID = @Min_ID);
   SET @Min_ID = @Min_ID + 1;
 END
```

Step 3:
Use that @ColToInsert in the below Dynamic SQL

```
  SET @DySQL = 'INSERT INTO Table_A(' + @Dest_Col + ') SELECT ' + @ColToInsert + ' FROM table_B';

  exec (@DySQL);
```

Now at this step 3 I am not getting the expected result. No data is getting inserted into `table_A`. I can understand that in the `CASE` statement I have to make some fixes so that `convert...` portion becomes a string. And I am not able to do so.

Any clue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you need the temp table at all. You just need to aggregate using `STRING_AGG`.

You also need to quote the objects and columns using `QUOTENAME`, and you should use `sys.columns` etc rather than `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, which is for compatibility only.

```sql
DECLARE @tableA sysname = 't';
DECLARE @tableB sysname = 's';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = (
    SELECT CONCAT(
      'INSERT INTO ',
      QUOTENAME(@tableA),
      '(',
      STRING_AGG(CAST(QUOTENAME(cA.name) AS nvarchar(max)), ', '),
      ')
SELECT ',
      STRING_AGG(
        CASE WHEN cA.user_type_id <> cB.user_type_id THEN
          CONCAT(
             'CONVERT(',
             typ.name,
             CASE
               WHEN typ.name IN ('varchar','nvarchar','char','nchar','varbinary','binary')
                 THEN CONCAT('(', CASE WHEN cA.max_length = -1 THEN 'max' END, NULLIF(cA.max_length, -1), ')')
               WHEN typ.name IN ('datetime2','datetimeoffset','time','float','real')
                 THEN CONCAT('(', cA.scale, ')')
               WHEN typ.name IN ('float','real')
                 THEN CONCAT('(', cA.precision, ')')
               WHEN typ.name IN ('decimal','numeric')
                 THEN CONCAT('(', cA.precision, ',', cA.scale, ')')
             END,
             ', ',
             CAST(QUOTENAME(cB.name) AS nvarchar(max)),
             ')'
          )
        ELSE
          CAST(QUOTENAME(cB.name) AS nvarchar(max))
        END
        , ', '),
      '
FROM ',
      QUOTENAME(@tableB)
    )
    FROM sys.columns cA
    JOIN sys.tables tA ON ta.object_id = cA.object_id AND tA.name = @tableA
    JOIN sys.types typ ON typ.user_type_id = cA.user_type_id
    JOIN sys.columns cB ON cB.name = cA.name
    JOIN sys.tables tB ON tB.object_id = cB.object_id AND tB.name = @tableB
);

PRINT @sql;  -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=53466cb15f2a0677768f3dccc0fb0acb)

Comment: Thanks a ton. Just a quick question. Say I want to insert selected columns into table A. So can I write `WHERE cA.COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (<Column Name>)`?

Comment: Yes almost: `WHERE cA.name IN ('column1', 'column2')`

Comment: In real life situation, we have a `ID` column in table B but not in table A. Therefore in the above code we can hardcode that. Hence I was thinking to set the query like `NOT IN ('ID')`.

Comment: Yes perfectly fine